# Mobius strip homotopically equivalent to filled out torus

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Why is the **Mobius strip homotopically equivalent to $S^1 \times D^2$**?
The latter is a filled out torus. How do we deform it to get the Mobius strip? Im not very familiar with homotopic equivalence, so Im looking for intuition.

Comment: Can you show that it's homotopic equivalent to $\mathbb S^1$.

Comment: We can contract each of the $D^2$ to a single point, right? That way we would get $S^1$. How do we obtain the Mobius strip from this?

Comment: The Mobius strip is formed by gluing two sides of a square, so there is an $\mathbb S^1$ in the middle of it.

Comment: What do u mean by there is a $S^1$ in the middle of it?

Comment: Here's an attempt at a very intuitive explantion. Make a Möbius strip in the usual way, but before glueing the end draw a line lengthways along the middle of the paper. That gives the $S^1$ you want. At each point $p$ on that $S^1$, there is a line on the strip passing through $p$ at right angles to the $S^1$, going from one point on the boundary to another. "Fatten up" that line into a square meeting the strip transversely, then deform that square to a disk. Doing this for every $p \in S^1$ gives you $S^1 \times D^2$. Shrinking each disk back to a line gives the homotopy equivalence you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can think of the Mobius strip as the quotient space

$$[0,1] \times [0,1] /(0, x) \sim (1, 1-x)$$

So there is an $\mathbb S^1$ in the middle: $[0,1] \times \{1/2\}$.

Comment: I see, so then the Mobius strip is also homotopically equivalent to $S^1$, and thus homotopically equivalent to the filled out torus?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on John's answer, the quotient of the function $(x,y,t)\mapsto (x,y(1-t)+t/2)$, $(x,y,t)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]\times [0,1]$  is a deformation retraction from the Mobius strip onto a circle.